# How do I draw bold text on a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, paint

I want a Bitmap icon with bold text to draw it on map. I have a snippet to write text on image:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(PropertyMapList.this.getResources(),
        R.drawable.location_mark);
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(14);
paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
//paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
Bitmap copy = icon.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(copy);
//canvas.drawText(jsonObj.getString("district_name"), 5, canvas.getHeight()/2, paint);
String districtName = jsonObj.getString("district_name");
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout((districtName.length()>25 ? districtName.substring(0, 24)+"..":districtName)+"\n"+jsonObj.getString("total_properties"), paint, canvas.getWidth()-10,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.3f, 0, false);
canvas.translate(5, canvas.getHeight()/2); //position the text
layout.draw(canvas);
```

`setFakeBoldText(true)` doesn't work for me. I would like the text drawn on the Bitmap to be bolded.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use the `setTypeface` method on your `Paint` object to set the font to something with the bold style turned on.

```
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
```

Comment: setTypeface allows you to set a font.  Fonts have styles, like bold, italic, etc.  You can look at the constructors for Typeface and see how to create a font with that style.  Once you create one and set it via this call, all future draw commands with this paint will use that font.

Comment: I tried 6 or 7 answers, and this one was the only one that actually worked.

Comment: A shorter version would be: `paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)` rather than calling Typeface.create()

Answer (score 16):

For Custom Fonts:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/bangla/bensen_handwriting.ttf");
Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(font, Typeface.BOLD);
```

For Normal Fonts:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
// or
Typeface typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD;
```

and then

```
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin syntax to setup Paint for bold text

```
paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).also { it.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD }
```